# What is the meaning of "Jane raised the lights."

Tags: word-usage

It seems the idea of the author of above sentence is to say that Jane raised the lighting of a stage where a performance was being done. Is that correct usage, especially when 'lights' is plural?
I am thinking that we don't say 'raise headphones / mouth' but 'raise volume / voice' and similarly it should be 'raise lighting' or 'raise the light'. Am I correct?

Edit: Just to clarify, originally I did not have any clue that this expression comes from theatre parlance. I was asking about if the sentence is grammatical when meaning increasing the intensity of light and if 'raise' is commonly used in this sense. Sven's comment was good enough for me.

Comment: I believe that in theatre-speak, "raising the house lights" or "raising the stage lights" means turning up the lights in question (as opposing to "dimming" or "cutting" them).

Comment: Hi Jeevaka - you could very much say "raise the speakers" (imagine a theater or something with, say, 20 loudspeakers ...you'd mean raise the volume on all of them). If there's more than one light, you'd certainly say "raise [the level of] the lights".

Comment: Thanks! Searching for 'raising the house/theatre lights' turned up many results.

Comment: "Raise the lights" is a set phrase for increasing lighting intensity -- this may be used in theater or in any other environment, including, say, when adjusting the lighting in ones home.  (Of course on a stage it could also be used literally to mean "pull on the ropes that raise the frame containing the lights").

Comment: If you said "Raise the speakers" as Joe Blow suggests, the stagehands might raise them a couple of feet. It doesn't seem to be much used as a deleted form, as shown by [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raised+the+lights%2Craised+the+speakers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craised%20the%20lights%3B%2Cc0) and a Google search.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Thanks for the Ngrams. Yes, it seems that this particular expression is correct simply because it is used in theatre lingo.

Comment: @joe blow: to tell them to raise the volume, but leave the speakers in the same place, you would say "Turn up the {sound/volume}."

Comment: hi Brian. It's completely normal to say "raise" the speakers meaning raise the volume.  Secondly, **it is completely normal** that "raise the lights" can mean physically raise the lights (example, raise the 2Ks one meter higher on their stands), and indeed "raise the speakers" could mean to raise them up on their stands.  Note that ambiguities are completely commonplace in English. It's utterly unsurprising that "raise the lights" can mean either turn up the level of the lights, or, physically raise them. (Note that "turn up" has the same ambiguity.)

Comment: @Joe Blow It may be completely normal in stage parlance, but you will note that OP broadens the context in their second sentence. It's certainly not 'completely normal' outside the theatre. On the other hand, as HotLicks states ' 
"Raise the lights" is a set phrase for increasing lighting intensity -- this may be used in theater or in any other environment ... '.  A distinction needs to be made between the idiomaticity of the two expressions.

Comment: Hi Edwin: the issue is confusing: *"broadens the context in their second sentence."* Note that (1) it is utterly commonplace (FOR NORMAL CIVILIANS) to talk about raisiing / loweing a tv, ipod, video game, gps, radio, PC, mac, etc etc  -- the myriad of shit devices around us which create sound via loudspeakers.  (Recently someone screamed at me "lower those fucking flat things" re my magneplanars!)  **In contrast, regarding the staggeringly obscure notion** of changing the pots on lighting systems, a handful of human beings have ever had reason to even think about that issue...

Comment: .. notice as I mention below, there (-- it has just occurred to  me --) are a number of phrases .. such as "hang ten!" "action!" "stop the presses!" "belay that order" "break right!" and so on .. which (a) "everyone" absolutely knows but (b) nobody, only a tiny handful of specialists, ever actually uses.  So .. well I guess you get my point.

Comment: one important thought here: regarding the utterly commonplace English os saying "lower the TV" (obviously meaning the volume).  You're right Edwin, I gave the example of "lower these speakers" or "raise these damned headphones".  Of course you're correct, there are a miniscule number of people who work with "headphones" or "speakers" (ie, George Martin, etc).  But it's commonplace of course (for normal people) to use those forms with the things that create sound (eg, TVs, iPads, etc etc).

Comment: Edwin, i would like to get back to the critical core of the question: (1) the OP dounts that such ambiguities are **uttely commonplace** in English (the two possible meanings of raise). (2) the OP mistakenly feels that one idiom should "follow" another idiom's usage: English is spectacularly, fantastically, NON-rule based, from the spelling upwards.

Comment: Kind of agree with this being off-topic. However this was from: https://www.mentoringminds.com/national-total-motivation-ela-student-edition.html , 5th grade reading comprehension. Glad that kids' school decided to drop this material.

Answer (score 1):

In the US theatre you will hear *lights* far more often than *light*, probably because any given cue involves the levels for different instruments and sets of instruments moving in different directions at different rates.

In fact, *light* in any form is rarely heard, except "lights" as a form of address to the lighting crew. When a director or lighting designer or stage manager is talking to the crew they know they're talking about the level of lighting, so there's no need to mention that; conversations address areas or groups or circuits or cues rather than "lights" generally. What you'll hear during tech rehearsals is this sort of thing:

> House to half...house out.
>   Lights, can you gimme another couple points down left?
>   Take your cyc blues to 7 on a 30 count.
>   Let's put in 58a as a manual follow on his cross down — cheat 15 up a point and 12-13-14 down just a tad.

And by the time the show opens the SM will speak to cues:

> Lights, warning 16 ... go 16, thank you!

Comment: And I thought legalese was as crazy as it got.

Comment: Hm. Interesting how like, and how unlike, some of these are in UK theatre parlance. I think I'd say "up" rather than "raise", address the lighting people as "Lx", and take the cyc blues to 70. And "Stand by Lx 16 ... go!" And we tend to have lamps rather than instruments.

Comment: @ColinFine It may be 70 these days; I haven't been active in 20 years, and I rarely got to work with computerized systems. "Up/down" rather than "raise/lower" is US, too, but "lamps" are the light sources inside the instruments.

Comment: How the hell do you pronounce Lx ??  :O

Comment: @StoneyB: brain fart. I didn't mean "lamps", I meant "lanterns".

Comment: @JoeBlow: Ell Ex.

Answer (score 0):

1) "raise" can mean either (a) turn up the potentiometer or (b) physically raise.

It is **completely commonplace that English features ambiguities like this**.

2) regarding the plural ... there are many lighting devices on a stage.

2b) You ask if one can alternately use a singular form. Yes, that is commonplace.

3) Regarding things like TVs. Identically to lighting, it is normal to use *raise, lower, up, down*, to mean adjusting the volume. "lower that damned TV!"

{**NOTE** - you give the example of "loudspeakers". This is meaningless as only a handful of specialists work with loudspeakers. (They, of course, say "raise, lower" when referring to the setting for a particular loudspeaker.) For normal people, the example for audio is "lower that TV" "lower that iPad" etc.}

4) Re your penultimate sentence: one idiom has **no bearing whatsoever** on another idiom. (However, in fact, in this case usage is identical.)

See Stoney's answer for an excellent exposition of relevant stage idiom.

---

Just BTW regarding audio. The forms *raise, lower, up, down* are also used for an audio **"thing"** such as a particular track. For example, "bring up the strings now."

Also note: it's an interesting curiosity that using the word "level" for audio or lighting, is indeed also ambiguous!

Comment: I've given pieces of evidence that seem to strongly indicate that it's far from 'completely normal [as you claim in your comment above] to say "raise" the speakers meaning raise the volume'.  As tchrist has said, 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely ... personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers. –  While I'd agree that 'raise the lights' is an accepted idiom, familiar to non-thespians, I have never heard the expression 'raise the speakers'. There needs to be more than personal opinion in your answer.

Comment: Hi Edwin. Every single ... ascii character .. on this page is personal experience.  Stoney's entire answer is nothing more than personal experience. (I applaud it for that reason.)  I can utterly assure you that in, say, a recording studio, it is commonplace to refer to "raising" or "lowering" a speaker or pair of cans (look I used trendy insider lingo), or similar words that implicitly mean "the potentiometer" rather than the height of the object.  Funnily enough I just pointed to a pair of "cans" and screamed at someone "bring these up". If you don't believe me - ok. Regarding refernces,

Comment: , I always applaud when someone else brigs references to the table. Hopefully someone will!  perhaps something like those "behind the scenes" films of productions you know? (whether albums, movies, stage or whatever)  However, it's hard to believe it doesn't sound natural to you to imagine someone in a sound studio (or the audio dudes on a set or stage) pointing at a speaker and saying "bring this one 'up'", of course meaning the potentiometer - just as you say "up" "down" with lights, of course meaning the potentiometer.  (Again, of course, obviously, it can also mean the physical position.)

Comment: @JoeBlow In my day you "potted" audio up or down.

Comment: that's a fantastic point.

Comment: And of course nobody actually brings the light or sound level up anywhere; the techies just move a slider or key in a number and the hardware does the actual raising/lowering :)

Comment: I've checked usages on the first 50 or so non-duplicate Google hits for "raised the lights" and "raised the speakers". There are plenty of 'raised the light levels' usages (admittedly accompanied by too many cannabis-growing tips), but only two 'raised the sound intensity' usages, and those by persons using non-standard English. I believe it should be labelled 'jargon'.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think written examples (from goog) are relevant to what's common in speech .. whether it is "jargon" is a great question, I don't know. the only place, in the universe, where you could "raise the lights" is on a film set (or similar) or in the extremely few houses wired that way; everyone says "raise or lower" the volume on devices constantly. (I just yelled at a child "lower that thing" pointing at an iPad .. i .. whatever the hell).

Comment: come to think, "raise the lights" is one ofthose weird phrases (like "cut" or "stop the presses") that one person in a billion actually says but is common from movies.  (Again, essentially "nobody" ever has need to describe changing the pots on lighting: whereas every single living human being, constantly, every hour, describes changing volume levels (eg "put down the TV").  so I don't know.  the whole issue's kind of weird.

Comment: ironically the missus was just screaming "lower that!" while pointing at the GPS (you know how loud the voice on those things are in cars!)

Comment: @JoeBlow Is there any chance the the usage you mention is common in your geographical area, but not widespread? That could explain the Ngrams.

Comment: hi jeevaka, i don't really think so, i live and work all 'round the world.  you know, ngrams are generally not much help for spoken language right?

Comment: also Jeevaka, you have added **"I did not have any clue that this expression comes from theatre parlance"** ... I very much doubt that using "raise" comes "from the theater".  It would surely have been used the first time anyone, anywhere, well, "raised" lighting levels.  I even struggle to find another word to use.  (For me turning "up" lights seems strange .. you'd have to be really explicit along the lines "adjust he controls so the fixtures produce more light", or mention lumens or something.

Comment: "I was asking about if the sentence is grammatical" yes it is completely grammatical.  "and if 'raise' is commonly used in this sense" yes, I can hardly think of another way to say it.  Just as you say raise or lower a TV (meaning the volume), you would (in the incredibly uncommon situation where you can change the lumen production of lighting systems) say raise or lower the lights.

Comment: BTW!  people say lights "out" meaning off.  (turn the lights out, etc)  I have no idea why!